# AWS secret Manager Performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I have an api deployed in AWS Lamdba using cloudformation, I am connecting to database in it. Presently I am hardcoding the values.

The api call will be made 10000xs of time, will it be a good decision to use AWS Secret Manager to save the database connection details and or it is an overhead to the cost and performance.

Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_lambda.html

Comment: I would always use parameter store over secret manager unless there is a specific feature of secret manager you need. Parameter store is similar to secret manager except AWS forgot to charge for it.

Comment: @jordanm, Thank you so much. I will use parameter store, do you think there is any performance concerns that I should be worry about.